# Differentiability and partial derivatives at the origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm interested in checking if the following function
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},& \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0),\\
0, &\text{if } (x,y) = (0,0).
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable at the origin, and also I would like to compute its partial derivatives at the origin, if possible. For the differentiability, my claim is that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ since it's not continuous at $(0,0)$. Indeed, if we compute the limit in polar coordinates, we obtain that
$$
\lim_{r \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(r(\cos(\theta)+ \sin(\theta)))}{r} = \begin{cases}
\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta),& \text{if } \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) \neq 0,\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} 
$$
therefore the limit
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$
doesn't exist. For the partial derivatives at the origin, I obtain the following
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(h)}{|h|h} = +\infty
$$
and the same for the partial derivative with respect to $y$ at $(0,0)$. However, Wolfram Alpha says that the partial derivatives at the origin are both equal to $0$.

**QUESTION:**
**Is my reasoning right or have I done a mistake?**

Comment: I guess you are correct, but wolfram-alpha would be correct if the piecewise-function was defined to be $1$ at the origin instead of $0$. The value of $1$ is a more natural value for the function in a sense, owing to the fact that the function which is $\sin(x)/x$ for nonzero $x$ and $1$ for $x=0$ is a smooth function.

Comment: If $f(0,0) = 1$, the partial derivatives at the origin are equal to $-\infty$, aren't they?

Comment: I don't think so. It would become a question about the derivative of $$g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)}{|x|} & x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x=0 \end{cases}$$ at $x=0$. If I'm not mistaken, the right derivative would be $0$ and the left derivative would be $+\infty$.

Comment: Anyway, I'm worried about the computation of the partial derivatives in the original problem. I think that clearly I'm right, but I would like to make sure.

Comment: I agree with your finding that, in the case of the original problem, both partials are equal to $+\infty$ at the origin.

Comment: Suppose you take the derivative with respect to theta and evaluate it at $r=0$. If this is not a constant, the limit doesn't exist since its multivalued. This implies not continuous which in turn implies not differentiable. But in what sense did the earlier differentiation play a role in this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. Hence there can be no derivative. For let $x=0.$ Then you have $$\frac{\sin y}{|y|},$$ with limit $\pm 1$ according as $y>0$ or $<0$ as $y\to 0.$

Comment: And the partial derivatives at the origin don’t exist either?

Comment: @Smm No, they technically don't, although that singularity could be easily removed.

Comment: The OP is still correct to say that both partials of the given function equal $+\infty$ at the origin, though. So in that sense there is a derivative.